# IHttpAsyncHandler unloading

Tags: c#, iis, ihttphandler

I have a large COM object that needs to be called from a web service. So I implemented an IHttpAsyncHandler class, with the hope of holding a reference to the COM object. That way the load time would be diminished between requests. I am running IIS 6 on Windows 2003 server.

It would appear that the HttpHandler assembly (?) unloads after processing because my static lists are empty on subsequent calls. It happens even if the second call is pretty much immediate:

```
    public class x2Handler : IHttpAsyncHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{
    public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }
    private static List<AsynchOperation> _asynch = new List<AsynchOperation>();
    public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
    {
        AsynchOperation asynch = null;
        foreach( AsynchOperation op in _asynch){
            if (op.Completed){
                asynch = op;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (asynch == null)
        {
            asynch = new AsynchOperation();
            _asynch.Add(asynch);
        }
        asynch.Context = context;
        asynch.Callback = cb;
        asynch.State = extraData;
        asynch.StartAsyncWork();
        return asynch;
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

}
```

Whenever the process is called _asynch is empty. The application pool does not appear to have any settings on that would cause the assembly to unload.

How do I make the static variable hold its values between calls?

EDIT: I don't know whether it helps in figuring this out or not, but if I have a breakpoint and it is hit, I then remove the breakpoint, when the code executes again (because of another HTTP request) the breakpoint is still set.

EDIT: I added a destructor to the class and placed a breakpoint in it to determine what is killing the class, it is being called from a "Appdomain Transition".

EDIT: I have tried inheriting from IRequiresSessionState and then assigning a test value to the context.Session and the context.Application, both do not hold their values between calls. So is it possible that the application pool is being released between calls?

Comment: `List<T>` is not a thread-safe type. If you want to use it in a multithreaded environment you will have to synchronize the access to it using proper locking mechanisms.

Comment: `IHttpAsyncHandler` is for freeing up worker threads during long-running operations. I don't think this is your problem. You should better describe where you problem with the COM object is (and focus on that). Is it just holding a reference to it so it doesn't get unloaded?

Comment: @Codo Yes, I need to hold references to one or more COM objects so that they do not get unloaded. As it stands though, I can't even hold a reference to a POCO between calls.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was unrelated. Before calling the COM object I wrote a text file that the COM object could access. Then I pass in the name of the text file to the COM object. The problem was that I was writing the file into the current directory where the HTTPHandler was installed.

Hazarding a guess ASP.Net monitors the directory and ANY changes in the bin folder cause the application to unload after current processing has completed. So the application would unload for every call. Moving the text file resolved the problem